# Inject Service with Dagger 2

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

What is the best way to inject a service using Dagger2 in Android?

MainActivity.java

```
@Inject MusicService musicService;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ((ShortOrangeApp) getApplication()).getComponent().inject(this);
```

MusicService.java

```
public class MusicService extends Service
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Considering services are created with intents, at best what you can do is provide a `MusicServiceHolder` which *might* hold a Service instance, although it still feels a bit extreme.

Comment: Android Framework components are intended to speak to each other with `Intent`s. They might be across threads or across processes, so injecting a Java object is not always a good idea. It's also a potential source of memory leaks. You can use `Intent`s with data/bundles to communicate back and forth between `Activity`s and `Service`s, which can in turn call methods on themselves according to the data you send in the `Intent`.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm going to use an event bus to communicate with the service. It seems like the cleanest way.

Comment: I imagine your service is bounded to some application. If you need to provide this service elsewhere and you re afraid it is no longer ther, the best way i guess is to provide a Provider<MusicService> that will get the application.musicService instance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45341072/how-do-you-implement-daggerservice