# How do you implement DaggerService

Tags: android, android-service, dagger-2

I've looked at the basics as well as the class, but being new to dagger (or even dagger 2) I have no idea how I'm suppose to use this

Here is the dagger intent service: https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/android/DaggerIntentService.html

I understand the android intent service and the basics for implementing, but I can't seem to find info over the DaggerIntentService (and I also struggle at finding info for DaggerService)

My goal is to build it using TDD, but I really just need to understand the workflow for implementing a dagger based service

Thanks,
Kelly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This does not answer the `DaggerIntentService` problem, on purpose. `dagger.android` packages more or less do the same thing you can do manually by setting relevant component and module for the Intent service. So you might try following approach:

`ServiceComponent`

```
@Subcomponent(modules = ServiceModule.class)
public interface ServiceComponent{

    @Subcomponent.Builder
    public interface Builder {
        Builder withServiceModule(ServiceModule serviceModule);
        ServiceComponent build();
    }

    void inject(MyService myService);
}
```

`ServiceModule`

```
@Module
public class ServiceModule{

    private MyService myService;

    public ServiceModule(MyService myService){
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    @Provides public MyService provideServiceContext(){
        return myService;
    }

    @Provides public SomeRepository provideSomeRepository(){
        return new SomeRepository();
    }
}
```

Having in mind that you have root dagger component, for example `ApplicationComponent` which you instantiate in application `onCreate()` method, you'll need an additional public method in your application class.

`ApplicationComponent`

```
@Component(modules = ApplicationModule.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent{
    ServiceComponent.Builder serviceBuilder();
}
```

`ApplicationModule`

```
@Module(subcomponents = ServiceComponent.class)
public class ApplicationModule{

    public ApplicationModule(MyApplication myApplication){
        this.myApplication = myApplication;
    }

    @Provides
    public MyApplication providesMyApplication(){
        return myApplication;
    }
}
```

`MyApplication`

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{

    ApplicationComponent applicationComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
            .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
            .build();
    }

    public ServiceComponent getServiceInjector(MyService myService){
        return applicationComponent.serviceBuilder().withServiceModule(new ServiceModule(myService)).build();
}
```

Finally, your `MyService` :)

`MyService`

```
public class MyService extends IntentService{

    @Inject MyApplication application;
    @Inject SomeRepository someRepository;

    public onCreate(){
        ((MyApplication)getApplicationContext()).getServiceInjector(this).inject();
    }

    public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent){
        //todo extract your data here
    }
```

It might look complicated at first, but if you have dagger structure setup already, then its just two to three additional classes.

Hope you find it helpful. 
Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown @bajicdusko, and I'm still a little lost. 1. your service is implemented from Service instead of DaggerService or DaggerIntentService, so how does that implementation differ? 2. If the injection flow is the same as using a DaggerService, then why not do constructor injection?

Comment: @KellyTheDev Implementation above does not use DaggerService, nor DaggerIntentService. These two classes are part of dagger.android, which is not used above. What we did above is almost the same thing as those two classes would do, but manually, to show the workflow.
Regarding injection, I hope I understood your question -> Services cannot use constructor injection as you won't be instantiating services via its constructors. Even in DaggerService class, description states "A Service that injects its members in onCreate()." You could use const. injection on SomeRepository from above, though.

Comment: OK, I think I'm with you on this @bajicdusko (thanks again BTW). So everything above is manual, with that said I would need to 1. implement DaggerIntentService 2. Do property injection like `@Inject SomeRepository someRepository;` (which injects/wires-up at onCreate()). 3a. if I need a specific ApplicationClass ref, override onCreate method like shown above. 4. do stuff with onHandleIntent()

Comment: @KellyTheDev 
1 No, you don't need to extend `DaggerIntentService`. I've edited example above (this should be fully functional code btw), where `MyService extends IntentService` and everything is injected in `onCreate` method. 
You'll notice that I've added all details related to `ApplicationModule` and `ApplicationComponent`, as well as `MyApplication` class. 
2. If you need myApplication reference inside the service, we've injected it (I guess that's the point, once the DI is setup), and no additional work is needed. For injection of `MyApplication`, check `ApplicationModule` methods.

Comment: thanks for all the explanation @bajicdusko and especially your time! I'm a c# guy dusting off android / java skills, which is why I've got a lot of questions. On top of that, looking into Dagger 2 (which way back then it was using Guice) and trying to understand it better. The thing I'm still trying to figure out is: Why do they include the `DaggerService` and `DaggerIntentService` if you don't use them? Is it advised against usage, less control, more difficult to wire up?

Comment: No problems :), here to help. As I said in the first line, I didn't explain it on purpose, because you wanted to know the workflow. Once you figureout manual workflow then you can use `DaggerService`, implement `HasInjector` interface and with few more tweaks set it up and running. Basically, fewer steps, less complicated procedure with those android-ready-classes.
Now that you know how to do it manually, try it with DaggerService/Activity/Fragment classes ;)

Comment: Awesome solution, just looking for this. Thanks.