# How to Inject IntentService in Dagger2.11

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I am using Dagger2 released library in my project. I have defined AppComponent as:

```
  @Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AndroidInjectionModule.class, AppModule.class, ActivityBuilder.class })
public interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);

        AppComponent build();
    }

    void inject(TraderApplication traderApplication);
}
```

Then ActivityBuilder will define specific activity and related modules as:

```
 @Module
public abstract class ActivityBuilder {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = SplashActivityModule.class)
    abstract SplashActivity bindSplashActivity();
}
```

and SplashActivityModule is providing dependencies as:

```
  @Module
public class SplashActivityModule {

    @Provides
    SplashViewModel provideLoginViewModel(TraderRepository traderRepository, Application application, SharedPreferenceUtils sharedPreferenceUtils, AppExecutors appExecutors) {
        return new SplashViewModel(traderRepository, application, sharedPreferenceUtils, appExecutors);
    }
}
```

Now, I am calling a IntentService from SplashActivity(to load some setup data) but inside that IntentService I can't able to @Inject dependencies of SharePreference, AppExecuters etc. The AppModule is defined as:

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
@Provides
    @Singleton
    TraderRepository provideIssueRepository(TraderListRepositoryImpl repository) {
        return repository;
    }

 @Provides
    @Singleton
    SharedPreferences providesSharedPreferences(Application application) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(application);
    }
}
```

**Update_1:
and Inside SetupDataService I am trying to injecting like inside onCreate:

```
  public class SetupDataService extends IntentService implements HasServiceInjector {

    @Inject
        SharedPreferenceUtils mSharedPreferenceUtils;

         @Inject
            AndroidInjector<Service> fragmentDispatchingAndroidInjector;

            @Override
            public AndroidInjector<Service> serviceInjector() {
                return fragmentDispatchingAndroidInjector;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate() {
                AndroidInjection.inject(this);
                super.onCreate();
            }
    @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
            assert intent != null;

    //**update_2 :
    if(mSharedPreferenceUtils != null) //still null here after using @binds
    {
    }
 }
}
```

It doesn't allow us to inject, even if I tried to implement HasServiceInjector inside Application Class. It throws with:
'Cannot inject Service without @Provide or @Produce'.

**Update_1 ends here..

How to inject Intent service using Dagger2.11 release. I tried defining :

```
 void inject(IntentService intentService);
```

inside AppComponent, but still, I am getting NULL values while injecting dependencies.

**Update_2:

and the SharedPreferenceUtils class I am trying to inject in Service class returns null inside onHandleIntent :

```
@Singleton
public class SharedPreferenceUtils {

    //region Private Fields
    private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    private final String TAG = SharedPreferenceUtils.class.getSimpleName();
    private final Method APPLY_METHOD = findApplyMethod();
    //endregion

    @Inject
    public SharedPreferenceUtils(SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences) {
        this.mSharedPreferences = mSharedPreferences;
    }
}
```

**Update_2 ends here..

Any help here..

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the IntentService? Where in it do you call the `inject` method you showed us, and have you considered [using `@ContributesAndroidInjector` to inject the Service](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/java/dagger/android/AndroidInjection.java#L127)?

Comment: @JeffBowman please check the *Update_1 edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> even if I tried to implement HasServiceInjector inside Application Class. It throws with: 'Cannot inject Service without @Provide or @Produce'.

The correct thing to do here is to do exactly that: Have your Application implement HasServiceInjector. The point of `AndroidInjection.inject()` is that you're taking an object that Android creates, which consequently doesn't have natural access to your DI graph, and have it automatically cast the Application to HasServiceInjector so it can try to inject the service. See the implementation in [AndroidInjection](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/java/dagger/android/AndroidInjection.java#L127) (comments added):

```
public static void inject(Service service) {
  checkNotNull(service, "service");
  Application application = service.getApplication();
  // Don't even bother checking the service itself, just check the Application.
  if (!(application instanceof HasServiceInjector)) {
    throw new RuntimeException(
        String.format(
            "%s does not implement %s",
            application.getClass().getCanonicalName(),
            HasServiceInjector.class.getCanonicalName()));
  }

  // As long as serviceInjector() returns non-null...
  AndroidInjector<Service> serviceInjector =
      ((HasServiceInjector) application).serviceInjector();
  checkNotNull(serviceInjector, "%s.serviceInjector() returned null",
      application.getClass());

  // ...ask it to inject your service.
  serviceInjector.inject(service);
}
```

It sounds like your real problem is that you're trying to inject Service, which is not allowed: You can inject SetupDataService, but there isn't a binding that exists for Service or IntentService. You could add them yourself to a Module you install on the `@ContributesAndroidInjector` binding for your `SetupDataService`:

```
@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = SetupDataServiceModule.class)
SetupDataService bindSetupDataService();

@Module interface SetupDataServiceModule {
  @Binds Service bindService(SetupDataService service);
  @Binds IntentService bindIntentService(SetupDataService service);
}
```

...but unless you're writing reusable code that should work for multiple Services, or unless you have build graph constraints and are trying to avoid direct references to your SetupDataService in other pieces of code, you might want to just stick to injecting SetupDataService instead.

See [this answer from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48004539/1426891) for a little more background, including why you'd want to do this here for a Service but not for Fragments.

Comment: I tried using @ ContributesAndroidInjector inside AcitivityBuilder independently or even tried linking to SplashActivity -> contributeinjector. But unluckily both didn't worked. I am still getting null object while injecting SharedPreferenceUtils dependency. Did I miss something ? Thanks.

Comment: @prdp89 It's impossible to say if you'd missed something, as you haven't shown us where or how you're injecting SharedPreferenceUtils. Without a reproducible example, I have to guess based on your error messages.

Comment: just solved it today by following (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45341072/how-do-you-implement-daggerservice). What do you think about this generic approach for service module?

Comment: @prdp89 That answer shows you the _manual_ way of doing it; with `DaggerIntentService` and `@ContributesAndroidInjector`, you can automate away some of that boilerplate. In particular, the `ServiceModule` it shows is perfectly fine, but use of `@BindsInstance` can allow Dagger to generate more-optimized code. If you've got it working you might want to move on and revisit it later after you're more familiar with Dagger and dagger.android.